# Не получается сгенерировать нужный тип массива PHP

Tags: php, массивы, циклы

Внутри цикла по выгрузке данных я таким методом генерирую массив, все хорошо, кроме данных которые я не могу добавить

```
$arResult['TABLE'][$ob['PROPERTY_INITIATOR_VALUE']][$ob['PROPERTY_PRODUCT_NAME_VALUE']] += $ob['PROPERTY_QUANTITY_VALUE'];
```

Получаю такой ответ

```
Array
(
    [4938] => Array
        (
            [Карандаши] => 4
            [Бумага А4] => 7
        )

    [4909] => Array
        (
            [Блокноты 200 лист] => 9
            [Календарь настольный] => 3
        )

)
```

Есть второй массив где я собрал все элементы которые есть по списку

```
$arResult['TABLE_PRODUCTS'][$ob['PROPERTY_PRODUCT_NAME_VALUE']] = $ob['PROPERTY_PRODUCT_NAME_VALUE'];

Array
(
    [Карандаши] => Карандаши
    [Блокноты 200 лист] => Блокноты 200 лист
    [Бумага А4] => Бумага А4
    [Календарь настольный] => Календарь настольный
)
```

Не могу создать массив как указан выше, пример

```
Array
    (
        [4938] => Array
            (
                [Карандаши] => 4
                [Блокноты 200 лист] => 0
                [Бумага А4] => 7
                [Календарь настольный] => 0
            )
    
        [4909] => Array
            (
                [Карандаши] => 0
                [Блокноты 200 лист] => 9
                [Бумага А4] => 0
                [Календарь настольный] => 3
            )
    
    )
```

Как создать массив, или перебрать, что бы получился такой формат исходя из двух заданных данных. Хотя бы подсказку какую нибудь. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно использовать array_replace, чтобы заменять нужные позиции в шаблоне

```
$arr1 = [
    4938 => [
        'Карандаши' => 4,
        'Бумага А4' => 7,
    ],
    4909 => [
        'Блокноты 200 лист' => 9,
        'Календарь настольный' => 3,
    ]
];

$arr2 = [ 'Карандаши', 'Блокноты 200 лист', 'Бумага А4', 'Календарь настольный'];



$res = [];

$arr2 = array_fill_keys($arr2, 0);
foreach($arr1 as $k=>$v) {
    $res[$k] = array_replace($arr2, $v);
}

print_r($res);
```

в результате

```
Array
(
    [4938] => Array
        (
            [Карандаши] => 4
            [Блокноты 200 лист] => 0
            [Бумага А4] => 7
            [Календарь настольный] => 0
        )

    [4909] => Array
        (
            [Карандаши] => 0
            [Блокноты 200 лист] => 9
            [Бумага А4] => 0
            [Календарь настольный] => 3
        )

)
```

Comment: Круто! Спасибо большое!